# Problema con ejercicios en java

Tags: java

La verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo y no sé ni como empezar

Cree una clase llamada Automóvil con dos variables privadas distancia y tiempo. El programa tendrá un método, el cual retornará el cálculo de la velocidad, para ello utilice la siguiente fórmula: `v=d/t` *(Donde: v=velocidad, d=distancia, t=tiempo)*.      Implemente la clase y cree un objeto e invoque el método.

Comment: Lo principal sería investigar y leer un poco más sobre  [POO](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/index.html) , después de leer seguro que podrá implementar el problema que plantea.

Comment: Opino como @Dev.Joel, lo que te preguntan es lo más básico sobre POO. Inténtalo y si no te sale vuelve con la duda que tengas y el código que hayas intentado. Ánimo!

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no se ha demostrado ningún esfuerzo en resolver el problema expuesto

Comment: Si te hago el ejercicio ¿la nota me la pondrán a mi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un pequeño prototipo de la clase que necesitas es:

```
public class Automovil{ 
    private int distancia;
    private int tiempo; 

    //Constructor: cuando se cree un objeto automóvil se ejecutará el código que incluyamos en el constructor
    public Automovil (int dist, int tiem) {
        distancia = dist; // se mide en km
        tiempo = tiem;  // se mide en horas
    } 

    //Método para calcular y devolver la velocidad del vehículo
    public void getVelocidad () {
       return distancia/tiempo;
    }
}
```

Ahora necesitas otra clase que será la clase principal y la entrada del programa:

```
public class Ejercicio {
    //Esta es la entrada al programa 
    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        Automovil car = new car (100,1);
        System.out.println(“Va a una velocidad de “ + car.getVelocidad() + “km/h”);

    } 
}
```